# Suggestions for drone simulator with ROS + Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, moveit, tum-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I am looking for a decent starting point for a drone project. I've checked the TUM_SIM (http://wiki.ros.org/tum_simulator)

And it seems quite stable, nevertheless, anyone has some experience with drones and ROS? What do you recommend? And also for the motion planning, should moveit work for a task like this? Or should I look into other 3d planners?
Thanks for the tips!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275417/suggestions-for-drone-simulator-with-ros-+-gazebo/) by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 700 on 2017-11-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-11-08**:
It's a little hard to give suggestions without any knowing what you're looking for.

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2017-11-09**:
Sorry if I was being a bit to vague, I am looking for a good simulator package to integrate with gazebo (like the tum_sim) in which I can simulate an environment, control my drone and plan movement.I know gazebo is powerful enough but I don't want to start from scratch, so far the tum_sim looks good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

my experience with drones is connected with the use of the [gazebo](https://dev.px4.io/en/simulation/gazebo.html) simulator in conjunction with the [mavros](http://wiki.ros.org/mavros).

MAVROS - [MAVLINK](http://qgroundcontrol.org/mavlink/start) - [PX4](https://dev.px4.io/en/)

another one Microsoft [AirSim](https://github.com/Microsoft/AirSim), but i didn't use it.

---

Originally posted by [0xd1ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/27403/0xd1ma/) with karma: 92 on 2017-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2017-11-10**:
Thanks! This seems just what I need!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[hector_quadrotor](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor) is a good one I've used with success.

I'm not sure what can be used for 3D planning though. I'm pretty sure MoveIt does not support that (I think it only supports planar holonomic platforms) but I could be wrong.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-11-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1